# Odd jsr destination in SuperH disassembly w/ Ghidra

Tags: firmware, ghidra, superh

I'm reverse engineering firmware from an old sampler/groovebox that uses a Hitachi SuperH-3 7706 processor, making great progress.  Out of the 8M or so of code, everything looks and lines up correctly.  However, in a few spots I see some stuff that makes me scratch my head and I'm not sure what is going on...

This function looks a lot like another one in a different area, which eventually calls memcpy().  This version of it makes a jsr to the middle of a function (0x8C010D20) and doesn't make a lot of sense given what is being stuffed into the function argument registers (see 0x80018e82 for actual jsr). And the 0x400B is definitely a jsr r0.

Here is the disassembly of the caller and the callee.  What am I missing here?

```
-- Caller --
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     undefined __stdcall rom_copy_to_ram_maybe(int param_1)
     undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
     int               r4:4           param_1
     undefined4        Stack[-0x4]:4  local_4                                 XREF[1]:     80018e70(*)
     undefined4        Stack[-0x8]:4  local_8                                 XREF[2]:     80018e72(*),
                                                                                           80018e88(*)
                     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe
80018e70 2f e6           mov.l      r14,@-r15=>local_4
80018e72 4f 22           sts.l      pr,@-r15=>local_8
80018e74 24 48           tst        param_1,param_1
80018e76 d5 06           mov.l      @(DAT_80018e90,pc),r5=>DAT_a0400000              = A0400000h
80018e78 8f 01           bf/s       LAB_80018e7e
80018e7a 6e f3           _mov       r15,r14
80018e7c d5 05           mov.l      @(DAT_80018e94,pc),r5=>SUB_a0000000              = A0000000h
                     LAB_80018e7e                                    XREF[1]:     80018e78(j)
80018e7e d0 06           mov.l      @(->FUN_8c010d20,pc),r0                          = 8c010d20
80018e80 d4 06           mov.l      @(PTR_DAT_80018e9c,pc),param_1=>DAT_8d800000     = 8d800000
80018e82 40 0b           jsr        @r0=>FUN_8c010d20                                TODO: this makes no sense... it'
80018e84 00 09           _nop
80018e86 6f e3           mov        r14,r15
80018e88 4f 26           lds.l      @r15=>local_8+,pr
80018e8a 00 0b           rts
80018e8c 6e f6           _mov.l     @r15+,r14
80018e8e 00 09           nop
                     DAT_80018e90                                    XREF[2]:     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e76(R
                                                                                  rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e76(R
80018e90 a0 40 00 00     undefined4 A0400000h
                     DAT_80018e94                                    XREF[2]:     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e7c(R
                                                                                  rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e7c(R
80018e94 a0 00 00 00     undefined4 A0000000h
                     PTR_FUN_80018e98                                XREF[2]:     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e7e(R
                                                                                  rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e7e(R
80018e98 8c 01 0d 20     addr       FUN_8c010d20
                     PTR_DAT_80018e9c                                XREF[2]:     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e80(R
                                                                                  rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e80(R
80018e9c 8d 80 00 00     addr       DAT_8d800000
```

````
-- Callee --
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     uint __stdcall FUN_8c010d10(char param_1)
     uint              r0:4           <RETURN>
     char              r4:1           param_1
     undefined4        Stack[-0x4]:4  local_4                                 XREF[1]:     8c010d10(*)
                     FUN_8c010d10                                    XREF[4]:     8c010a82(c), 8c010b14(*),
                                                                                  8c010cec(c), 8c010d08(*)
8c010d10 2f e6           mov.l      r14,@-r15=>local_4
8c010d12 74 bf           add        -0x41,param_1
8c010d14 64 4c           extu.b     param_1,param_1
8c010d16 e1 19           mov        #0x19,r1
8c010d18 34 16           cmp/hi     r1,param_1
8c010d1a 8f 02           bf/s       LAB_8c010d22
8c010d1c 6e f3           _mov       r15,r14
8c010d1e a0 01           bra        LAB_8c010d24
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     undefined FUN_8c010d20()
     undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                     FUN_8c010d20                                    XREF[2]:     rom_copy_to_ram_maybe:80018e82(c
                                                                                  80018e98(*)
8c010d20 e0 00           _mov       #0x0,r0
                     LAB_8c010d22                                    XREF[1]:     FUN_8c010d10:8c010d1a(j)
8c010d22 e0 01           mov        #0x1,r0
                     LAB_8c010d24                                    XREF[1]:     FUN_8c010d10:8c010d1e(j)
8c010d24 6f e3           mov        r14,r15
8c010d26 00 0b           rts
8c010d28 6e f6           _mov.l     @r15+,r14
8c010d2a 00 09           nop
8c010d2c 00 09           nop
8c010d2e 00 09           nop```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I'm reading it right but it seems `FUN_8c010d20` performs a part of the epilog processing:

1. Copy `r14` (frame pointer) to `r15` (stack pointer)
2. pop (saved?) `r14` from the stack and return.

I'm not sure why this is done in a separate function instead of inline but I suspect it may be caused by over-aggressive "shared code" optimization (sometimes also called *reverse inlining*), when the compiler (or more commonly linker) scans the binary for common code sequences (especially at the end of functions) and replaces them by calls to a common function to reduce total code size. This can bring substantial code size savings but in this case it basically replaced two instructions by a function call which itself takes more space (especially if we add the 4-byte function address literal).

Comment: That definitely seems to be what it is doing, but given all the setup in rom_copy_to_ram_maybe, including putting values in the registers for function arguments, it seems odd that nothing is done.  8c010d20 is in the middle of the function at a label (setting r0 to 0), then falls through to the other label (sets r0 to 1) and then returns.  Seems like a lot of setup for what amounts to either a NOP or returning a 1.

Comment: @telengard maybe check if code is being copied around or some memory remapping is going on

Comment: I will go over it again, I've spent a lot of time reversing to the point I'm pretty confident with the memory map and any code being copied around (which does happen).  thanks.  I guess that confirms that what is going on doesn't totally look right.  :)